# Editing values within camel context

Tags: mysql, xml, routes, apache-camel

Is it possible to make changes to values within camel context? Please refer to the script below.

In the script, before the insert statement, I would like to make some changes to `${body}` like remove 'address' and 'location' from `body`, then I will delete `address, location` from the table, and then insert the `values` into the table.

I know that I can make changes to the body within the source script (basically where it is coming `from`). However, I would like to know if changes can be done within xml file. If it can be done, then any guidance or help would be highly appreciated!

Thanks

```
<route id="text101" streamCache="true" errorHandlerRef="EH" handleFault="true">
    <from uri="fromQueue:QUEUE?selector=datatype LIKE '101%' AND messageid='12345'" id="fam101"/>
      <choice id="c101">
        <multicast>
             <pipeline>
                 <setBody id="body101">
        //body have these values: 12, tom, smith, 674-328-4933, tomsmith@gmail.com, 111 s road CA US, California
        <simple>insert into database1.table1 (customerid, firstname, lastname, phone, email, address, location) values ${body}</simple>
                </setBody>                      
                 <to uri="jdbc:myDatabase" id="d101"/>
             </pipeline>
          </multicast>
    </choice>                         
</route>
```

Comment: write a processor in between and make changes to the body

Comment: In this case, which data format has the content received from your queue?